# .NET/C# - What is the best option instead of an ActionBlock<T> (or Channel<T>) for speed?

Tags: asynchronous, task, producer-consumer

[corefxlab](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab) has something called a [Channel](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Channels) which is a really nice implementation of an async P-C queue and definitely does what I'm looking for.  I'm curious if there's an implementation that ultimately had a similar API to `ActionBlock<T>`:

1. Must be able to accept/deny from multiple producers.
2. Only needs to have one consuming task but would be preferable that it continue processing until empty.  Then 'wait' for new items.

A `Channel<T>` is much faster than an `BufferBlock<T>` but I'm just curious if given the specific requirements if there was something even faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a readme by Stephen Toub, Channels might end up being the underlying implementation around some Dataflow blocks.  Channels wins for P-C queue async speed.